# Utf-8 output from make4ht to odt format

Tags: tex4ht

I'm using `make4ht` to convert a document to odt, and I'd like the underlying `content.xml` to be in utf-8 encoding. I'm using the `u` option of `make4ht`:

```
make4ht -uf odt filename.tex
```

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Hello World!!!

áéíóúâêîôûüãõç.

\end{document}
```

The resulting `.odt` is displayed correctly, but the underlying `content.xml` renders the accented characters as:

```
<text:p text:style-name="First-line-indent">   &#xE1;&#xE9;&#xED;&#xF3;&#xFA;&#xE2;&#xEA;&#xEE;&#xF4;&#xFB;&#xFC;&#xE3;&#xF5;&#xE7;.
   </text:p>
```

(even though the UTF-8 header is in place: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`).

With:

```
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,ooffice,charset=utf-8" " -cmozhtf -utf8" " -coo"
```

I do get a proper utf-8 encoded `content.xml`. I also tried to pass these same arguments to `make4ht`, to no avail. What should I do to convince `make4ht` to deliver an utf-8 encoded `.odt` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The development version of `make4ht` now supports filters in the `ODT` output, so it is no longer necessary to update the `ODT` files using `zip` methods.

Simplified build file can look like this:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local utfchar = unicode.utf8.char
local process =  filter {
  function(content)
    return content:gsub("%&%#x([A-Fa-f0-9]+);", function(entity)
      -- convert hexadecimal entity to Unicode
      print(entity,utfchar(tonumber(entity, 16)))
      return utfchar(tonumber(entity, 16))
    end)
  end
}

Make:match("4oo$", process)
```

It is just necessary to use temporary file names produced by `tex4ht`, so instead of `content.xml` it is necessary to process file with a `.4oo` extension, which contains the document text.

---

Original answer:

Unicode characters in `content.xml` are escapes as XML entities by `xtpipes` command, which post-process the file in order to fix some issues regarding to math and sections. `xtpipes` can be requested from `t4ht` command using `-cooxtpipes` option, `make4ht` uses this option by default for the `ODT` output.

If you use the same arguments as for `htlatex` and ommit `xtpipes`, `make4ht` will produce identical result, with Unicode characters:

```
make4ht sample.tex "xhtml,ooffice" " -cmozhtf -utf8" " -coo"
```

---

```
<text:p text:style-name="First-line-indent">   áéíóúâêîôûüãõç.
```

But I would advise against disabling `xtpipes`, because you can end with invalid ODT file.

Instead, it is possible to convert the entities to Unicode using `make4ht` build file:

```lua
local mkutils = require "mkutils"
local zip = require "zip"
local utfchar = unicode.utf8.char


-- use function to change contents of the ODT file
local function update_odt(odtfilename, file_path, fn)
  -- get name of the odt file
  local odtname = mkutils.remove_extension(odtfilename) .. ".odt"
  -- open and read contents of the requested file inside ODT file
  local odtfile = zip.open(odtname)
  local local_file = odtfile:open(file_path)
  local content = local_file:read("*all")
  local_file:close()
  odtfile:close()
  -- update the content using user function
  content = fn(content)
  -- write the updated file
  local local_file_file  = io.open(file_path,"w")
  local_file_file:write(content)
  local_file_file:close()
  os.execute("zip " .. odtname .. " " .. file_path)
  os.remove(file_path)
end

Make:match("tmp$", function(name, par)
  update_odt(name, "content.xml", function(content)
    return content:gsub("%&%#x([A-Fa-f0-9]+);", function(entity)
      -- convert hexadecimal entity to Unicode
      print(entity,utfchar(tonumber(entity, 16)))
      return utfchar(tonumber(entity, 16))
    end)
  end)
end)
```

Becase the ODT file is zipped in the same step as `xtpipes` are called, it is necessary to open the ODT file, read `content.xml` from it and then pack again.

The content seems to be correct then:

```
<text:p text:style-name="First-line-indent">   áéíóúâêîôûüãõç.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And, given that the reencoding is done at a later stage, is the `-u` option required?

Comment: I also take your advice in keeping `xtpipes` and using the makefile, which works like a charm. In the same vein, if I may ask, in your tutorial, you mention that the use of `NoFonts` can produce some side effects. Are they enough to raise concerns?

Comment: @gusbrs the `-u` option is not required, Unicode output is used implicitly in the ODT mode.

Comment: @gusbrs `NoFonts` will disable font formatting for font switches like `\huge`, `\tiny` or `\bfseries`. all font changing commands must be properly configured to produce some stylled element. It really depends on your document if it causes any issues, but if you use only standard commands, it should be OK.

Comment: I see. I'll dig some more on the issue, and perhaps come back with something specific. Thus far, I've noticed results depend on the particular font family I use in the document. Thank you again for the info.

Comment: @gusbrs yes, special configuration file must exist for each font, it is quite possible that some less commons fonts may contain bugs in these configuraton files

Comment: `libertine` and `computer modern`? ;)  (best results thus far with `mathpazo`). But wait, I'll investigate further before anything. Thanks again.

Comment: `computer modern` should be OK. do you get wronch characters or wrong formatting?

Comment: Wrong characters no, but wrong sizes. But I haven't tried to control things to see what really was going on. So, as mentioned, I'm not yet sure.

Comment: @gusbrs wrong sizes are possible, I would need to see  an example.

Comment: I'll try to produce a MWE then.

Comment: michal Closer scrutiny with computer modern do not support the existence of any problems with it. Some glitches in specific environments (`thanks`, `url`, and a custom list environment) are clearly related with conversion and likely configurable. The use of `libertine` though results in a corrupt `.odt`.

Comment: @gusbrs yes, please make a MWE. I will look at it later, I still need to fix the `makecell` package and redo the `odt` support in `make4ht`

Comment: michal, here is [one for computer modern](https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/742c706b6c8d7f0bfc981ae71fbed489) and [another for libertine](https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/f6914d1cfd3ded35ae09c50092ec58c7). As I mentioned, for computer modern there is no real issue, just some glitches which are configurable. For libertine, a simple Hello World document is sufficient to break output.

Comment: @gusbrs try to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with Libertine example, it seems there are no configuration files for Libertine in the default OT1 font encoding

Comment: michal, Indeed `[T1]{fontenc}` gets this small libertine example to work. The same is not true with my full test document where I do have `T1` as usual (I could not isolate the problem, but I do get an error message `ERROR: attempt to index local 'local_file' (a nil value)`). But, as mentioned, from my point of view, font choice is not really a problem as long as I can reach satisfactory odt output with one of them. So unless these things interest you (in which case, I'm at your disposal for testing) there is no need to worry.

Comment: @gusbrs I think you got another error before this one, because it seems that `content.xml` is missing. it is necessary that config file exists for all fonts, so some is obviously missing even for T1 encoding.

Comment: @gusbrs the development version of `make4ht` now supports simplified method of filtering of the text.

Comment: michal.h21 Testing done. Both on the MWE in question and on my larger/complexer test file. And, except for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435596/105447) (which I'm not sure the new filtering was supposed to handle), everything works very nice indeed! There's an abundance of `span` environments around accented characters, but as far as I can tell that is "normal" and probably can be handled with the `cleanspan` filter (I haven't tried it yet though). Thank you very much!

Comment: @gusbrs that's fine. The math character issue is a different one, but it may be simillar to the span elements around accents, it should be fixable using DOM filters, similar to one that are already used for HTML

Comment: @michal.h21: Instead of `UTF` Characters how to get Entity Values like `&#x00A7;` instead of `§`?

Comment: @Balaji you can extract the `content.xml` from the ODT file, run some filter, and save it back.