# Non ascii characters for text in math mode for ODT output with tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

> This is related but, as far as I grasp, somewhat different from [Utf-8 output from make4ht to odt format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435290/105447).

I'm using `make4ht` to convert a LaTeX document to ODT and, within it, I have some equations which contain some text with non ascii characters, and I haven't been able to obtain good results with it thus far.

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{importação}{consumo}
\]

\[
  \frac{\text{importação}}{\text{consumo}}
\]

\[
  \frac{\text{importa\c{c}\~ao}}{\text{consumo}}
\]

\[
  \frac{\mbox{importação}}{\mbox{consumo}}
\]

\[
  \frac{\textrm{importação}}{\textrm{consumo}}
\]

\[
  \frac{\textnormal{importação}}{\textnormal{consumo}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Building it with:

```
make4ht -f odt document.tex
```

The result in the odt is the following:

[image]

Underlying it, we have:

- For the equation without any text commands:

  - in the .odt file: `{i m p o r t a ç ã o} over {c o n s u m o}` (thus with a space added for every character)
  - in the `content.xml` for the corresponding equation within the .odt:

`<math:mfrac><math:mrow><math:mi>i</math:mi><math:mi>m</math:mi><math:mi>p</math:mi><math:mi>o</math:mi><math:mi>r</math:mi><math:mi>t</math:mi><math:mi>a</math:mi><math:mi>&#xE7;</math:mi><math:mi>&#xE3;</math:mi><math:mi>o</math:mi></math:mrow> 
       <math:mrow><math:mi>c</math:mi><math:mi>o</math:mi><math:mi>n</math:mi><math:mi>s</math:mi><math:mi>u</math:mi><math:mi>m</math:mi><math:mi>o</math:mi></math:mrow></math:mfrac>
    </math:math>`

(My interpretation is that every letter is here considered a variable and put in the respective `<math...>` environment. So, this might eventually be considered correct, though it results different in output).

- For all other forms (that is, with text commands within math mode):

  - in the .odt file: `"o" over "consumo"` (thus, missing braces (I'm not sure they're required though) and, most importantly, missing part of the text)
  - in the `content.xml` for the corresponding equation:

`<math:mfrac><math:mrow><math:mstyle><math:mtext>importa&#xE7;&#xE3;o</math:mtext></math:mstyle></math:mrow> 
    <math:mrow><math:mstyle><math:mtext>consumo</math:mtext></math:mstyle></math:mrow></math:mfrac>`

Thus, the text is actually there, but doesn't get rendered by LibreOffice. If I edit any of these `content.xml`s with `importação` directly and repack, the .odt file results corrupted.

So, how could I get better results for text in math mode for ODT output, particularly with (some of) the text commands above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in LibreOffice, it has obviously problem with Unicode characters encoded as XML entities, as it renders only part of the word that follows the entities. Conversion of entities to characters seems to fix this, so we can reuse the code from my [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435296/2891) to do the conversion also for maths:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local utfchar = unicode.utf8.char
local process =  filter {
  function(content)
    return content:gsub("%&%#x([A-Fa-f0-9]+);", function(entity)
      -- convert hexadecimal entity to Unicode
      print(entity,utfchar(tonumber(entity, 16)))
      return utfchar(tonumber(entity, 16))
    end)
  end
}

Make:match("4oo$", process)
Make:match("4om$", process)
```

Math is saved in files with `4om` extension, so this build file executes the conversion process on files with that extension as well. The results seems fine:

[image]

Comment: Works marvelously indeed! Thank you very much once again!!

Comment: @gusbrs I've expected some issues with XML elements, this seems like really dumb bug on LO side. Their MathML support seems to have lots of issues. Anyway, I've updated `make4ht` to use this filter by default for the ODT output.

Comment: It does seem so. As to the use of this filter by default, I was thinking of suggesting it, as beyond reaching a "nicer" `content.xml` it appears to be better handled than the Unicode as XML entities by LO. So, I thank you a ton yet again!

Comment: @gusbrs I've made more fixes in the `ODT` support, if you want to test that

Comment: Michal, that's great! I'll gladly do so (but I'll only be able to do so later in the week). In what direction did the new fixes go? (so I know where to focus attention in testing).

Comment: @gusbrs I've moved call to `xtpipes` (which often causes issues in Miktex) from `t4ht` command to the ODT format driver. I should be also able to check if `xtpipes` processed the file correctly and try to fix the XML if it didn't.

Comment: You've mentioned `xtpipes` to me before, as a command which "post-process the file in order to fix some issues regarding to math and sections". Could you extend somewhat on that? Or give me some pointer to more information on `xtpipes`?

Comment: @gusbrs the problem with xtpipes is that it is quite mysterious command. it is Java library that executes special XML file with XSLT or Java instructions. It doesn't have any documentation, but you can try to read the XML files in `$texmf/texmf-dist/tex4ht/xtpipes/`. I can read that it fixes hyperlinks and sections for the ODT output, so it is necessary in order to produce valid ODT files. I hope to replace it with make4ht filters in the future, because it doesn't seem ideal to use something that nobody understands :/

Comment: I see. Give me some time, and I'll see what I can figure out in order to do some meaningful testing. I'll report back as soon as I can.

Comment: @gusbrs sure, no need to rush, I will slowly add more features and fixes

Comment: michal, I haven't forgotten, I'm working on it. But I utterly failed to understand what `xtpipes` is about. So I went to trying to produce some test files in order to check odt results more systematically. But I'm not done yet. Please give me some more time.

Comment: @gusbrs `xtpipes` tries to fix some things that are hard to do from TeX, it is something like XSLT. It is just important that it is executed. By testing I meant just to check that it can be found by `make4ht` and it is executed near the end of compilation.

Comment: Mmh, that I can tell it does. But I thought you meant the resulting document, so I started some interesting stuff around here (not yet ready though).  :)

Comment: @gusbrs sure, real world documents testing is also important, in order to make new features and fix issues. for now I am happy that the current make4ht seems to work and we can focus on the document contents